# how to put token after post API using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I want to ask ... how to retrieve the token, after the POST API data has been executed

this is the data

```
$scope.SubmitText = function(form){
                    console.log($scope.email)
                    var params = {
                        asalKota: 76,
                        emailPemesan: $scope.email,
                        hargaBayar: 370000,
                        idAgenBerangkat: 31,
                        idPemesan: 1,
                        idArahTrayek: 23,
                        idSubTrayek: 15,
                        idJadwal: 2976,
                        jmlPenumpang: 2,
                        kotaAsal: 'Yogyakarta',
                        kotaTujuan: 'Jakarta',
                        metodePayment: 'transfer',
                        namaPemesan: 'Muhammad Soleh',
                        penumpangs: [
                            {
                                gender: 'pria',
                                id: '1',
                                kursi: '30',
                                nama: 'Muhammad Soleh',
                                kategoriUsia: 'dewasa'
                            }
                        ],
                        telponPemesan: '089634756000',
                        tgl: '2018-01-30',
                        tujuanKota: 1,
                        waktu: '15:30',
                        zonaWaktu: 'WIB'
                    };
                    $http.post('http://dev.otodata.co.id:8181/order/tiket/' , params)
                    .then(function(data){
                        $scope.SubmitText = data;
                        console.log($scope.SubmitText);
                        window.location.href = "https://app.sandbox.veritrans.co.id/snap/v2/vtweb/" + $scope.SubmitText.redirect_url;
                    });
                };
```

but when I execute, the token is not picked up. how to get the tokens to take?
[imageTokenHere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgKcK.png)

please help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following code.

```
    $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : "YOUR_URL",
            headers : { 'Authorization': 'Token ' + accessToken }
        })
        .success(function(data, status){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function (error){
            console.log(error);
            deferred.reject();
        });
```